# How to separate an image's color channels into NSView's layers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsview

How to separate an image's color channels into `NSView`'s layers?

Example:

- The image's R-channel assign to NSView's layer 1;
- The image's G-channel assign to NSView's layer 2;
- The image's B-channel assign to NSView's layer 3.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: does that mean, you would have NSImage which will be filled with the RGB Data across the Image, Now you have 3 views and in each view you want to fill with Image's R , G and B Color separately